# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic mouTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms. (with confluent kafka)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, timeoutexception

I am using Confluent Kafka and have the required topic is already present. I am getting the below exception while sending data to `Kafka`.

> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic mouTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

```
Below  is my config class:

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableKafka
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapServers);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

Below are the gradle dependencies:

```
    dependencies {

        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
        implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams'
        implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
        implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients'
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:$springBootVersion"
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter', version: '8.1.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '6.3.0'
        compile "com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2"
        compile "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6"
        compile "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2"
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7"
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.3.5.RELEASE'
        compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11"
        compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.2.3"
        compile "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.8"
        compile 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java-extended-scalars:1.0'
        compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.12.0'
        compile group: 'com.graphql-java-kickstart', name: 'playground-spring-boot-starter', version: '5.10.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.0'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.4'
        runtimeOnly 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:altair-spring-boot-starter:8.1.0'
        runtimeOnly 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:voyager-spring-boot-starter:8.1.0'
        testImplementation 'com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter-test:8.1.0'
        testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion"
        testCompile "io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:$restAssuredVersion"
    }
```

My rest endpoint:

```
 @GetMapping("/sendOfferDataToKafka")
    public String allocateOffers() {
     Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
     .withPayload("data")
     .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "mouTopic")
     .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, "999")
     .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, 0)
     .build();

      System.err.print("message" + message.toString());

      kafkaTemplate.send(message);

      return message.toString();
 }
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us your list of topics in the cluster. Otherwise, verify your bootstrap servers config is correct in the app